# which react native webview version i should use to overcome Invariant Violation: Native component for "RNCWebView does not exist"

Tags: react-native-webview

Invariant Violation: Native component for "RNCWebView does not exist"

i had downgrade its version to 11.0.1 but still same issue webview\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\webview\RNCWebViewManager.java:289: error: cannot find symbol
view.getSettings().setAppCachePath(ctx.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
^
symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
location: class WebSettings